# New pandas dataframe column value using previous and current row values with date criteria

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, loops, numpy

I am currently using a formula in Excel for a calculation that I would prefer to do in Python to automate my processing (other data manipulation is done there, and this is the last piece). If a date value in column "Date" is past a certain date, I would like to calculate column G using a combination of previous and current row values. In Excel I used the following formula to accomplish the calculation: 

Pasted in cell G3. 

=IF(B3<=DATE(2018,11,4),D3,(G2-D2+E3+F3))

```
A   B                    C       D       E       F       G
0   2018-10-14 00:00:00  30.5    169.6   -       -       169.6 
1   2018-10-21 00:00:00  23.2    141.0   -       -       141.0 
2   2018-10-28 00:00:00  23.1    125.5   -       -       125.5 
3   2018-11-04 00:00:00  22.6    160.1   -       -       160.1 
4   2018-11-11 00:00:00  22.8    -       -       -       137.6 
5   2018-11-18 00:00:00  26.5    -       -       -       114.8 
6   2018-11-25 00:00:00  18.5    -       -       -       88.3 
7   2018-12-02 00:00:00  21.6    -       50.0    -       69.8 
8   2018-12-09 00:00:00  21.7    -       -       -       98.2 
9   2018-12-16 00:00:00  20.8    -       50.0    -       76.5  
10  2018-12-23 00:00:00  21.1    -       -       100.0   105.8 
11  2018-12-30 00:00:00  18.7    -       50.0    -       184.7 
12  2019-01-06 00:00:00  22.0    -       -       50.0    215.9
```

I have tried using many combinations of np.where, loc, iterrows, shift, for loops, etc. but I can't get the correct output. I appreciate your help.

Comment: did you convert your Date column to daettime format first?

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you describe what the Excel formula is doing?

Comment: Maybe you want to start by making sure your data is properly placed in a data frame and that the type of data in each column is right.

Comment: Your Excel formula is referring to cell `E1`, but this cell is a string (with value `E`), correct?

Comment: I edited the original post to clear up confusion I caused with cell references and column names. Column G - if the date in B is past 11-4-2-2018 - takes the previous row G value, subtracts the previous C value, and then adds current row E and F values.